# pdf.js hello world example

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I have cloned pdf.js from github and when I run http://localhost:8888/web/viewer.html it works fine. But when I run the simple hello world example http://localhost:8888/examples/helloworld/index.html I get an error in the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: PDFNetworkStream is not a constructor
    at eval (api.js:206)
    at <anonymous>
```

I am running gulp server as described in the example.

Any idea why the simple example is not working for me?

Comment: Please include your code.  Looks like `PDFNetworkStream` is not initailzed properly.

Comment: I havn't actually done any code yet. I cloned pdf.js it from https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js and want to do some experiments using the  https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld example. Just trying to run this unmodified using gulp server. I assume my gulp server is running correctly as http://localhost:8888/web/viewer.html is running correctly. So my question is why do I get this error in the helloworld example?

Comment: See also https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/8722

Comment: @async5 yes that works.